# angular7 WARNING in Circular dependency detected:

Tags: angular7

I am trying to register a service toa specific module with the help of 'provideIn' attribute in my angular7 app.

**test.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestComponent} from './test.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [TestComponent]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

**test.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestServiceService } from '../test-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service: TestServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**test-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TestModule } from './test/test.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: TestModule
})
export class TestServiceService {
  val = 3;
  constructor() { }

  getDetails() {
    return this.val;
  }
}
```

when I run my app it shows below error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TestComponent -> TestServiceService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TestComponent -> TestServiceService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TestServiceService!
```

when I change provideIn atrribute value as 'root' everything works fine.How can I register a service to specific module with the help of 'provideIn' attribute in angular7?

Comment: This might be a helpful resource to understand and solve your issue: https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-angular-6-dependency-injection-providedin-vs-providers-85b7a347b59f

Answer (score 0):

TestService has to be depend on TestModule in order to use providedIn to provide the service to the module. This creates a circular dependency, because TestModule has to depend on TestComponent which depends on TestService. Define the provider in the module so that the module depends on the component and the service.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    TestService
  ],
  exports: [TestComponent]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

Define the service as Injectable, and set providedIn to null.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: null
})
export class TestServiceService {
  val = 3;
  constructor() { }

  getDetails() {
    return this.val;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change test.component to this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestServiceService } from '../test-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
  providers : [TestServiceService]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service: TestServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and if you want to have single instance of service in module change test.module.ts to this :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestComponent} from './test.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers :[TestServiceService ],
  exports: [TestComponent]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

do one of them